# Help me understand linearly separability in a binary SVM

Tags: algorithms

I have a question pertaining to linear separability with hyperplanes in a support vector machine.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machineclassifier.):

> ...formally, a support vector machine
>   constructs a hyperplane or set of
>   hyperplanes in a high or infinite
>   dimensional space, which can be used
>   for classification, regression or
>   other tasks. Intuitively, a good
>   separation is achieved by the
>   hyperplane that has the largest
>   distance to the nearest training data
>   points of any class (so-called
>   functional margin), since in general
>   the larger the margin the lower the
>   generalization error of the
>   classifier.classifier.

The linear separation of classes by hyperplanes intuitively makes sense to me. And I think I understand linear separability for two-dimensional geometry. However, I'm implementing an SVM using a popular SVM library (libSVM) and when messing around with the numbers, I fail to understand how an SVM can create a curve between classes, or enclose central points in category 1 within a circular curve when surrounded by points in category 2 if a hyperplane in an n-dimensional space V is a "flat" subset of dimension n − 1, or for two-dimensional space - a 1D line.

### Here is what I mean:

[image: circularly enclosed class separation for a 2D binary SVM]

That's not a hyperplane. That's circular. How does this work? Or are there more dimensions inside the SVM than the two-dimensional 2D input features?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is something called the *kernel trick*. Google will find you some nice explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, the kernel tricks embeds your original points to a higher dimensional space (in fact, in some cases infinite dimensional - but of course the linear subspace generated by your actual points is finite dimensional).

As an example, using the embedding $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,x^2,y^2)$ (that actually corresponds to a quadratic kernel, I think) then the equation of an arbitrary ellipse becomes linear.

Answer (score 1):

[Cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997454/help-me-understand-linear-separability-in-a-binary-svm) my question at StackOverflow. More responses there.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Andrew Ng's website for a tutorial on SVMs.
www.stanford.edu/class/cs229/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf

Yeah, in this case I believe that the feature space and what you are representing are two different dimensions.