# Understanding linear separability

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

Having read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability) and [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/help-me-understand-linearly-separability-in-a-binary-svm) on the topic of *linear separability*, I still lack the understanding of this concept to explain any more than the most rudimentary euclidian example of it:

[image: linearly separable example 1][image: linearly separable example 2][image: linearly separable example 3]

I understand that a set of dots on a 2D plane is linearly separable if a straight line can be drawn through it. This specific instance of a linear separable problem makes intuitive sense to me, but I am struggling to apply this knowledge to help me understand why other problems might be linearly separable. For example, why is the OR gate classifier linearly separable?

```
Input 1 | Input 2 | Output
   0    |    0    |   0
   1    |    0    |   1
   1    |    1    |   1
   0    |    1    |   1
```

Without resorting to dots and lines on a page, can you compose a simple and intuitive explanation for why the above problem is linearly separable?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the inputs as pairs (x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>). As such, in your example, we have the following pairs:

```
(0,0)
(1,0)
(1,1)
(0,1)
```

These pairs have the following labels ("correct answers"):

```
(0,0) -> 0
(1,0) -> 1
(1,1) -> 1
(0,1) -> 1
```

Now, let's go ahead and plot these pairs and colour the data points based on the label value (red for 0, blue for 1):

[Plot (PNG image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgziq.png)

We can draw a single line that separates the data points in the 2D plane. Thus, this dataset is indeed linearly separable.

Comment: What I'm after is some kind of higher level explanation; something that will help me understand what linear severability looks like in higher dimensional space

Comment: Visualising linear separability in higher dimensional space is difficult, and to my knowledge, there is no single trick to help you determine if your data set is linearly separable.